# R. Bar plot format. Remove false/true boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using a bar plot with this script:

```
gene_expression_data <- data.frame(Germinal = c("CDH1", "NF1", "ATM", "BRIP1", "AXIN2", "NBN", "RAD51C"),
Freq_mut = c(13.08, 4.46, 3.17, 1.29, 0.89, 0.79, 0.69))

gene_expression_data |>
mutate(Germinal = fct_reorder(Germinal, rev(Freq_mut), mean)) |>
ggplot(aes(x = Germinal, y = Freq_mut)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = 100), stat = "identity", fill = '#e0e0e0') +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(y = Freq_mut,
label = sprintf("%2.1f ", round(Freq_mut, 1))
), adj = 0, nudge_y = 1, size = 3) +
facet_wrap(~ Freq_mut < median(Freq_mut),
scales = 'free_x', ncol = 2
) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100)) +
labs(y = 'mutation frequency (%)', x = '') +
theme(
panel.background = element_blank(),
strip.text.y = element_blank(),
axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, size = rel(1)),
panel.grid = element_blank()
)
```

But I need to do some changes:

a) it plots also on the top a false/true box, that I want to remove.

b) How can I separate all columns uniformly?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: The "true" and "false" labels are for your facet wrap - how do you want them to appear? If you want them all in one plot then why are you faceting?

Comment: I mean, if you see, CDH1, NF1, ATM and BRIP1 columns are separate with a grosor, but between BRIP1 and AXIN2 are bigger. I think it is because my previous code was in horizontal, and I have tried to adapt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to mark the median of the bars, you could use `geom_vline()` to put a line between the two bars where the median is and remove the faceting.  Here's what that would look like:

```r
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
gene_expression_data <- data.frame(Germinal = c("CDH1", "NF1", "ATM", "BRIP1", "AXIN2", "NBN", "RAD51C"),
                                   Freq_mut = c(13.08, 4.46, 3.17, 1.29, 0.89, 0.79, 0.69))

gene_expression_data |>
  mutate(Germinal = fct_reorder(Germinal, rev(Freq_mut), mean)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Germinal, y = Freq_mut)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = 100), stat = "identity", fill = '#e0e0e0') +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Freq_mut,
                label = sprintf("%2.1f ", round(Freq_mut, 1))
  ), nudge_y = 3, size = 3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=4.5, col="black", linetype=3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100)) +
  labs(y = 'mutation frequency (%)', x = '') +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, size = rel(1)),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>